# how to give two different date to same query in php?

Tags: php

I have two date format one is 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-10 and i have time two time one is 20:00:00 to 23:59:59 and 00:00:00 to 07:00:00 and i am using the for loop for iteration start date to end date and i expect  the following

query:

```
select * from user where login >='$starttime' and logout <='$endtime' and  date='$StartDate';
```

Expect Result:

```
select * from user where login >='20:00:00' and logout <='23:59:59' and  date='2013-01-01';
select * from user where login >='00:00:00' and logout <='07:00:00' and  date='2013-01-02';
```

how to use if condition to get the expect result

Comment: first remove the one where clause from query. two where clause will give the error.

Comment: Please share the code you are using to generate the two mentioned queries

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user where (login >='20:00:00' and logout <='23:59:59' and  date='2013-01-01') OR (login >='00:00:00' and logout <='07:00:00' and  date='2013-01-02');
```

if the times are identical but you need this for a range of date:

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
WHERE `login` >='20:00:00' AND `logout` <='23:59:59' AND  `date` between '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-02';
```

Comment: becase date is different and how to make two querys

Comment: you need to make more than one query?
can i see the code?, you question is not so clear now!

Comment: i have used this  $k=0; if($k == 0){
      $starttime1 = '20:00:00';
     $endtime1='23:59:59';
      
      $k = 1;
      
    }
    else if($k == 1)
    {



         $starttime1='00:00:00';
      $endtime1 = '07:00:00';
          
      $k=0;
        $StartDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($StartDate."+ 1 days"));
    }

Comment: i not getting the result

Comment: i need the two query with two different date and time please help me

Comment: Sorry man, still not clear! what you are getting and what is the expected results? try to explain more but in your question body, not in the comments!